# Catch AuthenticationException in Python Paramiko

Tags: python, ssh, exception, try-catch, paramiko

```
import paramiko

host='x.x.x.x'
port=22
username='root'
password='password'

cmd='dmidecode > a' 

ssh=paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(host,port,username,password)
try:
    stdin,stdout,stderr=ssh.exec_command(cmd)
    outlines=stdout.readlines()
    resp=''.join(outlines)
    print(resp)
except paramiko.AuthenticationException as error:
    print "ERROR"
```

I'm unable to catch the `AuthenticationException`.
Can anyone suggest me any other way to not break the script and only display the error?

Answer (score 3):

[`AuthenticationException`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/ssh_exception.html#paramiko.ssh_exception.AuthenticationException) happens in [`SSHClient.connect`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/client.html#paramiko.client.SSHClient.connect):

> **Raises**: **[`AuthenticationException`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/ssh_exception.html#paramiko.ssh_exception.AuthenticationException)** – if authentication failed

And your `SSHClient.connect` call is not in your `try` block.

This should work:

```
try:
    ssh.connect(host,port,username,password)
    stdin,stdout,stderr=ssh.exec_command(cmd)
    outlines=stdout.readlines()
    resp=''.join(outlines)
    print(resp)
except paramiko.AuthenticationException as error:
    print "ERROR"
```